# my email just hacked, no 2 factor auth. request or new sign in? Am I infected?

Tags: email, gmail

Gmail.

I just received two emails sent from my own account that I did not send. They are in my sent messages as well so were not spoofed.

I have on this account(and all my accounts):

- STRONG unique password, changed frequently
- 2 factor authentication tied to my phone
- backup email

I received no 2 factor code, new sign-in alert, or ANY notice at all of an account sign-in before receiving the messages from myself.

The attacker did not even try to actually do anything, like change my password or phone number, but just spammed a bunch of other email addresses from me and cc'd me(?).

The only possible way I can think of this happening is someone hijacking the signed-in session of gmail on my desktop, why explains why there was no new sign-in attempt.

How possible do you think this is given that I run Chrome on Linux, no Windows at all? Should I consider my desktop to be infected and wipe it?

Please, beyond changing all my passwords again, what should I do?

Answer (score 3):

It's a simple spoofing attack. Gmail is showing sent items not based on what was truly sent but on "from" address that matches your e-mail address. So you received an e-mail that has your e-mail address as to/cc/bcc and from at the same time, you will see in there but the e-mail wasn't sent from your account.

to check that, grab headers from original of one of the spam emails and drop it in [this tool](https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/messageheader/), and you will see under section "from" who originated it.

Comment: This happened to a lot of people with gmail accounts today (see [Gmail help forums: My account is sending spam emails](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/jtXGmic9dkc;context-place=forum/gmail)). Apparently telus.com had a [problem with their SPF config](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=16895030), and some spammer was taking advantage of it. That, and for some reason Gmail trusts the "From" address (which it really shouldn't).